# Как сделать setTimeout в python?

Tags: python

Мне нужно сделать запрос/заявку (request). Допустим я активирую одну функцию, если через 30 секунд если она не была подтверждена, вызывается другая функция, а если была подтверждена, то вызывается третья функция

В js есть setTimeout() и clearTimeout(), так вот я хочу сделать что-то подобное в python (асинхронно)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Аналог в Python для этих функций [Timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects)

```
def func():
    print "hello, world"


t = Timer(30.0, func)
if something: t.start()  # после 30 секунд, "hello, world" будет выведено
else: t.cancel() # иначе отменить
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
time.sleep(howManyToWaitInSeconds)
```

Comment: Это не асинхронно, да и отменить нельзя