# Как добавить таймер в последнее слово строки

Tags: python

Смог реализовать для целой стройки таймер, но есть необходимость сделать это для исключения последнего слова "Ждите", к примеру  чтобы time.sleep был 7секунд. Идей как добавить в исключение нет, даже близко

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
import time

time.sleep(5)
print('\x1b[39m +  "Работа идет.....Ждите")
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать setTimeout в python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1172042/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-settimeout-%d0%b2-python)

Comment: Нет, сейчас ознакомлюсь @vladimir-gonchar

Comment: Как я понимаю, Вам нужно вывести или строки по окончанию времени, или строки сразу, но действие по окончанию времени. Timer эту проблему решит (по аналогии setTimeout в js). Если нужно что-то другое -- уточните вопрос так, чтобы было явно понятно что требуется

Comment: @vladimir-gonchar в принт все выводится через 5 секунд, мне нужно сделать, чтобы слово "Ждите" выводилось чуть позже, к примеру, через 2 секунды после основного таймера. То есть, через 5 секунд выводится предложение Работа идет.....( и через 2 секунды выводится  или дополняется слово "Ждите".

Comment: "Красивее" :) и понятнее раз в секунду добавлять по точечке, на основе ответа от чистов_n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю тут подойдёт таймер. Отложенный вызов функции можно реализовать вот таким способом:

```
import threading
import time

def my_function():
    print("Функция вызвана по таймеру")

# Установка времени задержки в секундах 
delay = 7

# Таймер
timer = threading.Timer(delay, my_function)

# Запуск таймера
timer.start()

# Ожидание завершения потока (если нужно)
# timer.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть так, если я правильно вас понял:

```py
import time

time.sleep(5)
print('\x1b[39m +  "Работа идет.....', end='', flush=True)
time.sleep(7)
print('Ждите"', flush=True)
```

Comment: Да, все так. Спасибо! Буду разбираться теперь